# Is there an easy way to count characters in words in file, from terminal?

Tags: text-processing

I have 100 million rows in my file.

Each row has only one column.

e.g.

```
aaaaa
bb
cc
ddddddd
ee
```

I would like to list the character count

Like this

```
2 character words - 3
5 character words - 1
7 character words - 1
```

etc.

Is there any easy way to do this in terminal?

Comment: see also [Count line lengths in file using command line tools](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16750911/4023950)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
$ awk '{ print length }' file | sort -n | uniq -c | awk '{ printf("%d character words: %d\n", $2, $1) }'
2 character words: 3
5 character words: 1
7 character words: 1
```

The first `awk` filter will just print the length of each line in the file called `file`.  I'm assuming that this file contains one word per line.

The `sort -n` (sort the lines from the output of `awk` numerically in ascending order) and `uniq -c` (count the number of times each line occurs consecutively) will then create the following output from that for the given data:

```
   3 2
   1 5
   1 7
```

This is then parsed by the second `awk` script which interprets each line as "X number of lines having Y characters" and produces the wanted output.

---

The alternative solution is to do it all in `awk` and keeping counts of lengths in an array.  It's a tradeoff between efficiency, readability/ease of understanding (and therefore maintainability) which solution is the "best".

Alternative solution:

```
$ awk '{ len[length]++ } END { for (i in len) printf("%d character words: %d\n", i, len[i]) }' file
2 character words: 3
5 character words: 1
7 character words: 1
```

Comment: No need to sort in awk (numerically indexed arrays are sorted by default) (faster).

Comment: @Arrow I know. I have that solution commented out in my answer because [Sundeep beat me to it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/396862/116858) with a few seconds. I also allude to this with my last paragraph.

Comment: I believe the comment should be useful to the users of the solutions (not included in your answer (or Sundeep's) :-) …). Otherwise: include a comment to the same effect in your answer and I happily will remove my comments. :-)

Answer (score 10):

Another way to do it all with `awk` alone

```
$ awk '{words[length()]++} END{for(k in words)print k " character words - " words[k]}' ip.txt 
2 character words - 3
5 character words - 1
7 character words - 1
```

- `words[length()]++` use length of input line as key to save count
- `END{for(k in words)print k " character words - " words[k]}` after all lines are processed, print contents of array in desired format

Performance comparison, numbers selected are best of two runs

```
$ wc words.txt
 71813  71813 655873 words.txt
$ perl -0777 -ne 'print $_ x 1000' words.txt > long_file.txt
$ du -h --apparent-size long_file.txt
626M    long_file.txt

$ time awk '{words[length()]++} END{for(k in words)print k " character words - " words[k]}' long_file.txt > t1

real    0m20.632s
user    0m20.464s
sys     0m0.108s

$ time perl -lne '$h{length($_)}++ }{ for $n (sort keys %h) {print "$n character words - $h{$n}"}' long_file.txt > t2

real    0m19.749s
user    0m19.640s
sys     0m0.108s

$ time awk '{ print length }' long_file.txt | sort -n | uniq -c | awk '{ printf("%d character words - %d\n", $2, $1) }' > t3

real    1m23.294s
user    1m24.952s
sys     0m1.980s

$ diff -s <(sort t1) <(sort t2)
Files /dev/fd/63 and /dev/fd/62 are identical
$ diff -s <(sort t1) <(sort t3)
Files /dev/fd/63 and /dev/fd/62 are identical
```

If file has only ASCII characters,

```
$ time LC_ALL=C awk '{words[length()]++} END{for(k in words)print k " character words - " words[k]}' long_file.txt > t1

real    0m15.651s
user    0m15.496s
sys     0m0.120s
```

Not sure why time for `perl` didn't change much, probably encoding has to be set some other way

Comment: I _just_ added that to my own solution. Deleted it when I saw your's though. :-)

Comment: yeah I was debating to delete mine before saw your edit again :)

Comment: No need to sort a **numerically indexed** array. It is allways ordered with an increasing index. ( well, at least in awk :-) )

Comment: `length` without `()` works perfectly fine here, so it might be redundant to add braces. I'm using GNU awk,though.

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy yup, [gnu awk manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) says `In older versions of awk, the length() function could be called without any parentheses. Doing so is considered poor practice, although the 2008 POSIX standard explicitly allows it, to support historical practice. For programs to be maximally portable, always supply the parentheses`

Comment: This histogram strategy should be much faster than @Kusalananda's piping to `sort` approach, for the OP's 100 million rows.  Although if perf matters, perhaps perl or python would be faster than awk.  C could easily be faster if you want to spend some time optimizing it.  With lots of short lines, I wonder if this `awk` program can keep up with a fast disk?  Maybe disable field parsing, since you just need `length()`, if your AWK interpreter doesn't make that optimization on its own.

Comment: @PeterCordes added some perf numbers... not sure about disabling field parsing...

Comment: Cool.  I wonder if the time changes much if you `cat words.txt{,,,,,}` (repeat the file 1000 times), instead of repeating each line 1000 times.  Length parsing might have more branch mispredicts instead of falling into a pattern for 1000 lines.  And sort might have more work to do.  In C, if you already have an array of integers that you want to histogram, repeats can actually slow you down (serial dependency on store/reload to the same address repeatedly).  But I assume that this doesn't run anywhere *near* one increment per 5 clock cycles :P (store-forwarding latency on Haswell)

Comment: For perl performance, an actual array would probably be faster than a hash.  You'd only want a hash if you expect your keys to be sparse.  (Although AWK arrays always associative arrays, too.  I guess an interpreter could optimize them to actual integer-indexed arrays if the program being run would behave the same.  But perl probably doesn't, because it has a separate type for arrays.)

Answer (score 5):

Here's a `perl` equivalent (with - optional - sort):

```
$ perl -lne '
    $h{length($_)}++ }{ for $n (sort keys %h) {print "$n character words - $h{$n}"}
' file
2 character words - 3
5 character words - 1
7 character words - 1
```

Comment: If keys indexes are numerical: Does keys array need to be sorted in Perl?

Comment: @Arrow: This answer is using a hash (i.e. associative array with string keys), and those have undefined key order, so yes. In fact, the answer is slightly buggy because it's sorting the keys as strings, not as numbers. Adding `{$a<=>$b}` after the `sort` would fix that. Alternatively, one could use a normal array with numerical keys and just skip any keys where the value is zero / undefined.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Thanks, better now. What a difference curly braces make !!

Comment: It would be more efficient to use an array instead of a hash.  The OP wants millions of lines, so any overhead of checking and skipping zeros while printing is easily made up for by cheaper indexing.

Answer (score 5):

An alternative **one** call to GNU awk, using **printf**:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN { PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_str_asc"}
       {c[length($0)]++}
       END{
           for(i in c){printf("%s character words - %s\n",i,c[i])}
          }' infile
2 character words - 3
5 character words - 1
7 character words - 1
```

The core algorithm just collects character counts in an array.
The end part prints the collected counts formatted with printf.

Fast, simple, one single call to awk.

To be precise: some more memory is used to keep the array.
But no sort is called (numeric arrays indexes are set to be always traversed sorted upward with PROCINFO), and only one external program: `awk`, instead of several.

Comment: `for in` may happen to give numeric array indexes in numeric order at least for some values or in some awk implementations, but that is not required, not traditional, and definitely not universal. It does often happen for tiny sets like 2 or 3 or maybe 4; try 10 or 20 on every awk you have access to (without PROCINFO or WHINY_USERS in gawk) and I bet $50 at least one case isn't sorted.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Using [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Array-Sorting.html): I believe it is sorted now. :-)

Comment: `@ind_str_asc` sorts as strings, which will be correct for numbers only if they are all single-digit (as your example is); use `@ind_num_asc` if (any) values can be 10 or more. And although it's less of an issue now than it used to be, this feature is only gawk **4.0 up**.